# How to slurp file and process line by line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to slurp in a javascript file and send this over an ssh connection. It's a standard unix file with a single newline at the end of each line. Using Python 2.76.

When I slurp it in and print it, I get one character per line. I've looked at similar posts on here and I'm not getting the behavior those say I should.

```
def slurpWorkerCode(filename):
    file = open(filename, "r")
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    return data

ecma = slurpWorkerCode("/devel/backup/list.aksh")

for line in ecma:
    print line
```

Output:

```
<snip>
v
a
r

M
O
N
T
H
S
<snip>
```

Am I going about this wrong?

Thx for any help.

Comment: What did you expect instead? You've replaced all the newlines and you're iterating over a single string that holds the whole content of the file.

Comment: I get the same behavior if I omit the ".replace('\n', '')".

Comment: Yes, and it's not clear why you don't expect that! [`read`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) gives you one string. Iterating over strings gives characters. That's it.

Comment: Yea actually it was in the form I needed, it was my debug code that was wrong. *bonk* Much thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` returns a single string, so `data` (and thus `ecma`) are single strings. When you iterate over a single string, you get one character at a time. I suspect what you really want is

```
data = file.readlines()
```

so that `data` (and thus `ecma`) is a list of strings, one string per line.

Comment: `file.readlines()` is kind of old-fashioned. Just loop over the file object (`for line in file: ...`).

Comment: True, but in the context, a function called `slurpWorkerCode` makes more sense if it returns a list of strings, rather than a file object.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
```

`file.read()` returns the whole file as one big string. You could get a list of lines out of this by applying `.split('\n')`, but that's more work than needed.

The more standard way to read a file as a list of lines and strip off newlines is:

```
def slurpWorkerCode(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

A generator version would look like:

```
def slurpWorkerCode(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f: 
            yield line.rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe: +1, generator = nicer style.

Comment: The nice thing about a generator here is that you don't have to have multiple copies of the whole file in memory.

Comment: and don't grind the machine to a halt if the file is way larger than available RAM... :-)

Comment: Python: There's more than one way to do it, *and you can still read it.*